# Symfony4 - Creating https routes

Tags: https, routes, symfony4

I am trying to create a route under Symfony4 in https mode. My online research has taught me that I have to present the route in the annotation as follows: `@Route ("/lucky", name = "lucky", schemes = {"https"})`. But the request made from Chrome gives me the message "This site is inaccessible." Are there any other settings to perform?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. To accept HTTPS requests, a server must have a certificate. Since this is a local wamp server, wamp must be set to install an SSL certificate. The attached documentation explains how to do:
[enter link description here](https://www.it-connect.fr/mettre-en-place-une-connexion-ssl-avec-wamp%EF%BB%BF/)

Comment: Try to find a tutorial/doc in english, instead of french, as most of users here doesn't talk french (I guess).